# Mitm proxy with certificate pinned application

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, mitmproxy, certificate-pinning

I am trying to simulate MITM attack over signal's android messaging application. It's open source, so I put the `mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem` in android application for pinning and in the mobile trusted certificates too. I am still not getting any query to the server.
Error at the client end is

> NonSuccessfulResponseCodeException: Bad response: 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: Start looking at this: level 3. Good luck! https://techblog.mediaservice.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/HackInBo-2017-Winter-Edition-Federico-Dotta-Advanced-mobile-penetration-testing-with-Brida-141017.pdf

Answer (score 3):

If i understood well you are trying to attack a mobile that uses certificate pinning to connect with the API server.

If so then adding the `mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem` to the mobile trusted store is not enough, you need to configure the network security file `res/xml/network_security_config.xml` as per [google docs](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config).

If you still fill lost try to follow the article [Hands on Mobile Api Security Pinning](http://blog.approov.io/hands-on-mobile-api-security-pinning-client-connections) to see if it helps you to get back on track.

## EDIT

The following instructions are valid for the Android API level 24 and above.

> ##### Another Edit
>
> A better approach then using the bash script that I provide below is to use the free [Mobile Certificate Pinning Generator](https://approov.io/tools/static-pinning/) online tool to get the public key pin hash and to generate the proper Android network security config file for us:
> [image: Config tab on the web page for the Mobile Certificate Pinning Generator tool]
>
> [image: The Android tab on the web page for the Mobile Certificate Pinning Generator tool]

[Bash script](https://github.com/approov/currency-converter-demo/blob/82b0a04fb4857fb90ab38e7b3f543ef890b14410/bin/hash-certificate-public-key-from-file.bash) to generate the hash from the certificate public key:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Heavily inspired on:
#   * https://medium.com/@appmattus/android-security-ssl-pinning-1db8acb6621e#ecea

set -eu

Main()
{
    local certificate_path="${1? Missing path to certificate.}"

    local certs="$( cat ${certificate_path} )"
    local rest=$certs

    while [[ "$rest" =~ '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----' ]]; do

        cert="${rest%%-----END CERTIFICATE-----*}-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
        rest=${rest#*-----END CERTIFICATE-----}

        local certificate_name="$( echo "$cert" | grep 's:' | sed 's/.*s:\(.*\)/\1/' )"

        if [ -n "${certificate_name}" ]; then
            printf "\nCERTIFICATE NAME: \n ${certificate_name} \n"
        fi

        printf "\nCERTIFICATE PUBLIC KEY HASH:\n\n"

        echo "$cert" |
            openssl x509 -pubkey -noout |
            openssl rsa -pubin -outform der 2>/dev/null |
            openssl dgst -sha256 -binary |
            openssl enc -base64

        echo

        exit 0

    done
}

Main ${@}
```

Save the above bash script somewhere in your bin path and then use it like:

```sh
$ hash-certificate-public-key.sh ~/path/to/mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem

CERTIFICATE PUBLIC KEY HASH:

gsGj6crKw/RebflwkwGIKxngaZaVxP7UsUtuF71VKDw=
```

Now copy paste the hash and add it into this file [src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml](https://github.com/approov/currency-converter-demo/blob/82b0a04fb4857fb90ab38e7b3f543ef890b14410/mobile-app/android/app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>

    <!-- Official Android N API -->
    <!--https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/changes-to-trusted-certificate.html-->
    <domain-config>
        <domain>the-domain-to-pin.com</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user" />
            <!-- <certificates src="system" /> -->
        </trust-anchors>
        <pin-set>
            <!-- THE MITM CERTIFICATE HASH -->
            <pin digest="SHA-256">gsGj6crKw/RebflwkwGIKxngaZaVxP7UsUtuF71VKDw=</pin>
        </pin-set>
    </domain-config>

</network-security-config>
```

And now include it in the [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/approov/currency-converter-demo/blob/82b0a04fb4857fb90ab38e7b3f543ef890b14410/mobile-app/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L14):

```xml
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        <!--omitted-->
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
```

If not done already add the mitmproxy certificate to the user trusted store in your Android device, then recompile the app, and now you should be able to intercept the requests.

> **NOTE**:
>
> The code examples have been extracted from the [Currency Converter Demo App](https://github.com/approov/currency-converter-demo) repository, that was used as part of the article [Steal that API Key with a Man in the Middle Attack](https://blog.approov.io/steal-that-api-key-with-a-man-in-the-middle-attack) and article [Securing HTTPS with Certificate Pinning on Android](https://blog.approov.io/securing-https-with-certificate-pinning-on-android)